# Is it possible to add an extra height to equalizer height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I need to add an extra 35px to whatever the height calculated by Foundation Equalizer. Is this possible?

For example, if Equalizer height calculation is 350px, I would like 35px to be added on. So style created will be `height: 385px;` instead of `height: 350px;`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Init Foundation with this code:

```
$(document).foundation({
  equalizer: {
    after_height_change: function(){
      $('div[data-equalizer-watch]').height(function (index, height) {
          return (height + 35);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/Akarienta/pen/WQXLgp?editors=101)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you.